# sorting an array of objects

Tags: java, arrays

I have a method that sorts an array of objects by first names which prints out fine. However when i want to print the original order of objects it still prints out the sorted version. What can i change to fix this?

**Main method + other methods**

```
String[] firstNames= {"Fred","John","Amir", "James","Bob","Jay","Amber"};
String[] lastNames = {"Bond","Kates","Memar", "White","Marley","Brown","Nogofski"};
String[] idNumbers = {"R111111","A222222","AB11111", "KR22121","V311133","L242434","P102432"};
String[] employeeNum = {"1111","2222","3333", "4444","5555","6666","7777"};

Employee[] list = new Employee[firstNames.length];
list = listOfEmployees(firstNames,lastNames,idNumbers); // create the list of employees in one array    
System.out.println("List of employees before sorting...\n");
printEmployeeList(list); //print the list of employees
sortWithFirstName(list);
printEmployeeList(list);


public static void printEmployeeList(Employee[] list){
    String employees = Arrays.toString(list).replace("[", "").replace("]", "").replace(",", "");
    System.out.println(employees);
    }

public static Employee[] sortWithFirstName(Employee[] list){
  System.out.println("Sorting the list with the first name");
  {
boolean swap;
//String temp; //change this too
do
{
    swap = false;
  for (int i = 0; i < (list.length - 1); i++)
{
    if (list[i].getFirstName().compareTo(list[i+1].getFirstName()) > 0) //if first number is greater then second then swap
    {
        //swap

        Employee temp = list[i];
        list[i] = list[i + 1];
        list[i + 1] = temp;
        swap = true;
    }
}

} while (swap == true);
printEmployeeList(list);
}
 return list;
}
```

**Employee class**

```
public static class Employee{
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String idNumber;
    private String employeeNumber;
    private int employeeCount;

    /**
     * Constructor
     * @param firstName first name
     * @param lastName last name
     * @param idNumber id number 
     */
    public Employee(String firstName, String lastName, String idNumber){
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.idNumber = idNumber;
        employeeCount = 0;
    }
    /**
     * Accessors here
     */

    public String getFirstName(){
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName(){
        return lastName;
    }

    public String getIdNumber(){
        return idNumber;
    }

    public String getEmployeeNumber(){
        return employeeNumber;
    }

    // mutators here

    /**
     * @param firstName first name
     */
    public void setFirstName(String firstName){
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    /**
     * @param lastName last name
     */
    public void setLastName(String lastName){
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    /** 
     * @param idNumber id number
     */
    public void setIdNumber(String idNumber){
        this.idNumber = idNumber;
    }

    /**
     * @param employeeNumber employee number
     */
    public void setEmployeeNumber(String employeeNumber){
        this.employeeNumber = "";
    }
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        String result = "\nFirst name: " + getFirstName() + "\nLast name: " + getLastName()
                + "\nId number: " + getIdNumber() + "\nEmployee number: ";
        if(getEmployeeNumber() == null){
        return result + "No employee number has been assigned yet!\n";
    }
        return result + getEmployeeNumber() + "\n";
    }

}
```

Comment: Create local copy of employee list in your sorting method, then sort (and return) that local copy instead of original list.

Comment: Are you attempting to reprint the original order here `printEmployeeList(list); //print the list of employees
sortWithFirstName(list);
printEmployeeList(list);` ? If so then why would it reprint the original order if you rearranged the structure of your list array?

Comment: @J.Schei so make a copy of the array inside the sort method? something like `Employee[] copied = Arrays.copyOf(list, list.length)` ?

Comment: I would make your `Employee[] copied = java.util.Arrays.copyOf(list, list.length);` immediately after `list = listOfEmployees(firstNames,lastNames,idNumbers);` (not inside the sort method). Then you can call `sortWithFirstName(copied);` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you print the original order, then rearrange the list variable. If you print the list again, it will be rearranged because it is the same variable.

```
printEmployeeList(list); //print the list of employees
sortWithFirstName(list);
printEmployeeList(list);
```

You need to create a copy of the original list and rearrange that one instead (eg. listArranged), then if you want to print the original list you can access the first `list` variable.

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to create a new array intance when you sorts the original array don't do it directly in it but use the new instance so when you go back to the original you will find it as it was before
it's like create a sort copy from the original array